# showing that a function is a bounded linear functional

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, solution-verification, holder-inequality

I know that a bounded linear functional has these two properties:

for $A:V \rightarrow R$ and $V$ being a vectorspace we have:

(1) $A(x+y) = A(x) + A(y)$, for all $x,y \in V$

(2) $A(\alpha x) = \alpha A(x)$, for all $x \in V$ and $\alpha \in R$

(3) $|A(x)| \le C.||x||$, for all $x \in V$ and $C > 0$

To my Problem:

i need to show that $A_b:l^p(N)→R,(a_n)_{n∈N}\rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\inf a_n b_n$

,with $b = (b_n)_{n\in N} $ and $p,q > 1$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

is defined as a bounded linear functional on $(l^p(N),||.||_p)$.

I am trying to use "Holder inequality" but i was not successful.

I would appreciate it, if you know how to approache this problem and every other problems like this one.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity is obvious. Boundedness follows as you said by Holder's inequality:

$$|A_b(a_n)|=\bigg|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n\bigg|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n||b_n|\leq\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^p\bigg)^{1/p}\cdot\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n|^q\bigg)^{1/q}=\|(a_n)\|_p\cdot \|(b_n)\|_q$$

This is true for all $(a_n)\in\ell^p$, so, assuming that $(b_n)\in\ell^q$, $A_b$ is a bounded functional and $\|A_b\|\leq\|(b_n)\|_q$. Actually, equality holds, $\|A_b\|=\|(b_n)\|_q$, but what we did above is enough.

**edit upon request**: Linearity is very simple: let $\lambda,\mu$ be scalars and let $(a_n), (a'_n)$ be sequences in $\ell^p$. Also, let $N\geq1$ be a natural number. Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^N(\lambda a_n+\mu a'_n)b_n=\lambda\sum_{n=1}^Na_nb_n+\mu\sum_{n=1}^Na'_nb_n$$
As this is true for any $N$, let $N\to\infty$ to obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\lambda a_n+\mu a'_n)b_n=\lambda\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n+\mu\sum_{n=1}^\infty a'_nb_n$$
i.e. $A_b(\lambda(a_n)+\mu(a'_n))=\lambda A_b(a_n)+\mu A_b(a'n)$, which shows linearity.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Although it is obvious but i dont get it with linearity. Would you please guide me in the right direction :) @JustDroppedIn

Comment: @Elmagnifico I have added some details in my answer, have another look:)